# What on earth could this metaphor imply?

Tags: metaphors

Reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/respect-sick-twisted-coronavirus-hit-140554995.html) (emphasis mine), there are 2 lines,

> Chinese media have also singled out Matt Pottinger, a deputy national security adviser who delivered a direct appeal to the people of China — in Mandarin — to embrace democratic change.
>
> “**Everything Mr. Pottinger has done is like a weasel pretending to offer New Year’s greetings to a chicken,**” said a response on CCTV to his speech.

What would the Chinese media try to say with the metaphor?

Comment: This seems to be a metaphor directly translated from the Mandarin - these are quite common in translations of Chinese state media, and you might be better off asking Mandarin speakers. I imagine it means that he is a [wolf in sheep's clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_in_sheep's_clothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like a weasel trying to get close to the chicken (to eat it) by pretending to be a good neighbor.